# Parity Control programme, Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to do the [parity control](http://www.codeabbey.com/index/task_view/parity-control) challenge on Code Abbey.  I've been having trouble with it for months, but I finally have it...*almost*.  The output it returns is off by a few characters, and I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction.  I'm stumped, in part because my code is so sloppy even I can't really parse it (I'll fix that).

I hope this isn't too close to homework help.  I know you guys hate that.

```
import string

characters = string.letters + ' ' + '.' + string.digits

characters = zip(characters, [bin(ord(i))[2:] for i in characters])

nch = {}

squareseven = 128

for char in characters:
    # For readability.  a is the character, like A or ., b is the binary.
    a = char[0]
    b = char[1]
    if b.count('1') % 2 != 0:
        nch[a] = int(b, 2) + squareseven
    else:
        nch[a] = int(b, 2)

with open('input.txt', 'r') as O:
    O = map(int, str(O.read()).strip().split())

    decyphered = ''

    for binary in O:
        # If the number of ones is odd, 128 is added.
        if bin(binary)[2:].count('1') % 2 != 0:
            tmp = binary + squareseven
        else:
            tmp = binary

        # Because the ASCII binaries only go up to 255.
        if tmp < 256:
            if tmp in nch.values():
                for char, b in nch.iteritems():
                    if b == tmp:
                        decyphered += char

with open('output.txt', 'w') as output:
    output.write(decyphered)
```

Comment: its not homework we hate ... its lack of demonstrated effort ... it appears at first glance this question does not suffer from that (it looks like you gave it a pretty honest shake)

Answer (score 3):

most problems can be better attacked by breaking them into smaller sub problems

first write a method to help check the data

```
def check_char(n):
    """return ascii code if parity check success else None"""
    bits = "{0:08b}".format(n)
    if int(bits[0]) == sum(map(int,bits[1:]))%2:
        return n&0x7f #get rid of the parity bit when return ascii
```

then a method to handle a single line

```
def translate_line(line):
    ascii_codes = map(int,line.split()) 
    checked_values = [check_char(n) for n in ascii_codes]
    return "".join(chr(val) for val in checked_values if val)


print translate_line("65 238 236 225 46")
```

then just loop over your lines passing them in